# Upload an image from a React Native Expo App using Multer and put it into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, react-native, image, expo, multer

The React Native App based of EXPO and the connection to express server and the database is established, I want to eliminate the errors and get the data in the database. If I have forgotten any information, please let me know.

You find the code below: https://github.com/kjahandel/rn/blob/5d61862d6a84a8d15e3cf7f0e639f135a25966f0/uploadImage